# Sort by other column not working in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a clustered chart in Power BI. I would like to order the columns **within each cluster** based on custom order.

I followed steps suggested by v-haibl-msft on this post: [Custom Sorting in PowerBI?](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Custom-Sorting-in-PowerBI/m-p/128051#M54392). I created an "Order" table, with the `Type` column and a `Column` column which shows the true order of the "Type" column. Joined "Order" table to my table of interest, tried to sort "Type" column by "Column" but it did not work.

In the step shown by the following screenshot, I want to sort `Type` by `Column` where `Column` has values `1,2,3`, after sorting `Column`, it follows the order `1, 3, 2`.

Tried to restart Power BI, still no luck.

Why isn't it sorted as `1,2,3`? Is this a bug or am I missing any step?

[image]

---- Update:

Solution turns out to be very trivial. What I have done was correct, except that after sorting column `Type` by `Column` as shown in the screenshot, I need to **literally sort column `Column` again**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in **table view** - where what you are doing isn’t really making sense.

You set a different sort column to override how the categories are sorted in **canvas mode** visuals, not how they are sorted in the table view.

With your method, you can create e.g. a bar chart that have your `Type` column as categories, and the column order will be automatically set by the sorting applied using `Column`.

Answer (score 2):

have you resort the visual by hand? as visuals always be sorted by data in descending by default. after table steps you need to adjust sort of visual. see attached gif:

[image]

Comment: Hi Sia, yes I did, the thing is I don't want to sort by the original column name, which is `Type` here because its values do not represent the true order, and I had to create another column `Column`(which is the true order index) and associate it with the column type, then I want to sort by `Column`. However, `Column` is  not used in the visual as a variable, but `Type` is.

Comment: Hi Nilsinelabore, yes you do not need to add [Column] into the visual, just [Type] is fine. Would you let me see the visual as i want to see Y/X axis. And do you use [Type] as Y axis or other column? Please give me more information.

Comment: or you can send me pbix file to my emial address: zhangjx7@126.com

Comment: Hi Sia, I have identified the issue, as explained in the question update, thanks for your help :)

Comment: hi i see, yes you should use it inside of a visual, in table view it's not show. visual with [Type] in Y/X axis then do steps followed the gif.